# C Code not printing out the whole thing

Tags: c, libpcap

First of all, I am sorry if the question has already been asked, I couldn't find it (or anything similar).
My problem is something like this: 
I am writing some C code (network things) and, first of all, I just want to print out all the available interfaces of my NIC (let's say I have 30 lines until now, including preprocessor stuff). Everything is fine. After that, I wanted to add some extra stuff (capture some packets). So I write a few lines more (declare variables, call functions, check if returned values are OK and print out some stuff). Let's say I now have 50 lines. Now, if I compile and run my program, it prints out the interfaces (until line 30), but it ignores the rest. I even put a few random printf below, just to see if they are printed out, but they are not. 
If anyone knows what's wrong, please help.
Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<pcap.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h> 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  pcap_t* descr;
  const u_char* packet;
  struct pcap_pkthdr* hdr;

  char* user_input;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
  pcap_if_t* alldevs;
  if(pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf) != 0) {
    printf("Error while finding devs\n%s", errbuf);
    exit(1);
  }
  pcap_if_t* d = alldevs;
  while(d != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", d->name);
    d = d->next;
  }

  scanf("%s", user_input);

  struct in_addr addr;
  int ip, mask;
  int ret = pcap_lookupnet(user_input, &ip, &mask, errbuf);
  addr.s_addr = ip;
  printf("NETWORK: %s \n", inet_ntoa(addr));  

  // =======================================

  descr = pcap_open_live(user_input, BUFSIZ, 0, -1, errbuf);

  if(descr == NULL) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
  }

  packet = pcap_next(descr, hdr);
  if(packet == NULL) {
    printf("Error, packet is NULL\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("AAAAAAAAAAAAA\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, please post the code so we can read it and help you...

Comment: Don't describe your code.  *Show* your code. A description says "this is basically what the program does". Problem is, computers don't do "basically" what you tell them. They do **exactly** what you tell them. So show us **exactly** what you're telling the machine to do.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I will show you.

Comment: So, is this a case of your changes NOT taking effect? Then problem is in your build process. Perhaps you (your IDE, whatever) is running the wrong binary? Perhaps you get build error, but don't notice it? Check file timestamps, for example, does the binary get updated when you rebuild?

Comment: `char* user_input; ... scanf("%s", user_input);`  review this code.  Where will user input get saved?  What is the value of `user_input`?

Comment: should I use gets()?

Comment: Use `fgets()`  is the best approach.  But code still needs  a place to save the data.

Comment: @EQ_ALL_THE_WAY The point is that when you declare a pointer variable, you need to allocate memory for it to point to. Instead of declaring a pointer, you could declare an array.

Comment: Oh, that did it! Thank you so much!